# mac os gpt show command shows multiple Master Boot Record partitions in parts (MBR Part 12) on wiped internal hard drive

Tags: macos, partitioning, macbook-pro, mbr, gpt

I ordered a used apple oem ssd hard drive off of the internet to replace my macs fried ssd. I intalled it and booted to internet recovery to do a clean wipe and a clean install. Upon inspection of the newly installed hard drive, i found a gpt partition entry which contents contains a `MBR Part 12` when using the command `gpt show /dev/disk1` from the internet recovery terminal command line. The gpt man pages seem to have very limited documentation, and i have never seen the contents of a gpt partitiion listed as a master boot record in parts up until recently, including on a usb drive. Can anyone help me understand exactly why this record is appearing in the `gpt show` command and what it means exactly? Below are pics of the terminal output for the drive using fdisk, diskutil, and gpt show commands in the internet recovery terminal. Please help explain this?

[image: Diskutil info output for macbook oem ssd]
[image: gpt show mbr part 12 and fdisk output]

Comment: Thanks @Spiff, hopefully someone else familiar with this can give me a solid answer. Im very interested.

Comment: My first guess comment was wrong so I deleted it. See my actual Answer for what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

That output shows that your disk is formatted to use an ancient Master Boot Record (MBR) instead of a modern GUID Partition Table (GPT). "MBR part 12" is the `gpt` command's shorthand way of saying "This partition is of MBR partition type #12" (a.k.a. 0x0C, "0Ch"), which turns out to be "FAT32 with Logical Block Addresses (LBA)", a.k.a. "FAT32L" as you see in your `fdisk` output.

One way to put a disk into that state on macOS is to format it  with `fdisk -ia dos /dev/diskN` (where N is the appropriate disk number, like 0 or 1).

Please note that to use it as a Mac boot disk it must be reformatted to use a GPT instead of an MBR. I strongly recommend you use Disk Utility (or at least `diskutil`) to format it, rather than legacy, poorly-supported command-line tools like `fdisk` or `gpt`.

Comment: There's a possibility [however remote] that it is misinterpreting APFS. The 3 dots are the old skeuomorphic ones, pre-Yosemite, so it won't know what APFS is.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you referring to the ellipsis I had in my example `fdisk` command? That was just my way of omitting the disk identifier, which won't always be `/dev/disk0`. I've edited my Answer to replace the ellipsis with something more explicit. The `gpt` command's "MBR part N" is definitely giving the decimal representation of the partition type ID number from the MBR specs. I tried different partition types and the number followed the partition type as expected.

Comment: No, I mean the old-style red/yellow/green dots in the OP's picture, definitely pre-Yosemite - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QPjb.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh that. No it's not that. He said he wiped it from that Internet Recovery boot, so he wouldn't have been able to make it APFS. Also it was definitely FAT32L and identifying it correctly. I repro'd his situation on an old Mac I had around and ran some experiments to confirm my hypothesis before I posted this answer.